# Migrate from Struts MVC to SOA

Tags: struts, soa

I have a project where i need to migrate from Struts MVC model to SOA. 
What is the best practice to manage it from the architecture point of you. How the mapping between the two design pattern should be handled. I know the View tier in MVC should stay.   However, since Apache struts rely on Struts-configuration.xml file to forward the request to proper struts action, how this step should be handle in the transition. 
and if we have JSM for asynchronous communication, how the session beans should be treated.

I appreciate your help in this matter

Answer (score 1):

Design Pattern and architectures are two different things . SOA is more about an architecture and not specific to a vendor technology . Everything in SOA 's perspective is a Service , how we implement , which technology we use is completely our choice .Axis Framework are some Enterprise Service Bus which help Service Orientation in Java .